# iOS UITableView: changing background color of table overrides background color of cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have an issue where setting the background color of my tableView overrides the background colors I've set for my individual cells. To be more specific, I have a table with 3 rows: the top cell is dark gray, and the bottom 2 cells are red:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx9bm.png

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIColor *sectionBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.09f green:0.09f blue:0.09f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *menuItemBackgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = sectionBackgroundColor;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"MENU";
        cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
        cell.selectionStyle = false;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Schedule";
        cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Schedule.png"];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Contacts";
        cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Contacts.png"];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = false;
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is make all those empty, unused white cells on the bottom black. Based on my research, setting the tableView background color will do just that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C1eg.png

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However, as you noticed, this line of code changes the background colors of the top two cells to black too. I played around with this more and noticed a general pattern where every cell background color will be changed to black except the last one:

*(see 3rd image in the above link)*

Any ideas regarding what's happening here? Help would be appreciated!

---

---

Some things I've tried already that do not work (I would provide more links but my current rep doesn't allow me to):

A) Making the views in the cells opaque. Changing the colors of the different views in the cells.

```
cell.opaque = YES;
cell.backgroundView.opaque = YES;
cell.contentView.opaque = YES;
cell.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;
```

B) Setting the backgroundView of tableView nil.

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

C) Setting the background color of the backgroundView of tableView.

```
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: The backgroundView is nil by default, so cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor; won't do anything unless you've added a background view.

Answer (score 4):

> setting the background color of my tableView overrides the background colors I've set for my individual cells

That's correct. Annoying, isn't it? :) The problem is really just that  Either give the cell a colored `backgroundView` (much easier than it sounds), or else wait until `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, and set the `backgroundColor` of your cells there.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty annoying! Unfortunately as indicated in my post, I have tried both of these and they don't work :(

Comment: @Chun, did you see my comment? Did you add a backgroundView?

Comment: Ah I see now. Yes, this works-- thanks! I've also found another solution and will post that shortly.

Comment: @Chun, really it worked? Because I tried it, and it didn't, but making the table view's background color clear did.

Comment: No actually. I accidentally combined both solutions so that's why I thought it worked. What I tried exactly was:
`cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = menuItemBackgroundColor;`
Which doesn't work.

Comment: The fix was actually where you declare `tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`. The problem will be fixed only if you declare it in viewDidLoad, and not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround allows you to use the background colours specified in the storyboard, and avoid setting explicit colours in your code:

- In `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, while the background colour from the storyboard is still intact, save it, e.g. in a property of your custom `UITableView` subclass.
- Later, in `willDisplayCell:`, restore the `backgroundColor` with the value you saved in in  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.